# Difference between Interface and Class in Java

Tags: java

As per multiple articles in Java Interface and Class are completely different. Let me write an Interface.

```
package com.main.service;

public interface SomeService{
   public void someMethod();
}
```

But why below code is allowed in Java?

```
 com.main.service.SomeService.class;
```

I am using this code to get beans from Spring application context like below:-

```
 SomeService someservice = applicationContext
            .getBean(com.main.service.SomeService.class);
```

Comment: Interfaces and classes both are compiled to Java bytecode classes. Dependency Injection Containers allows you to pass an interface and it finds an implementation to be provided.

Comment: applicationContext
            .getBean returns you an implementation of the interface.

Comment: **.class** is a built-in language feature (a class literal) that looks like a public static final field

Comment: @aKilleR your comment is really to the point. But please explain more about .class feature and how it is working with Interface.

Answer (score 2):

The `.class` syntax at the end of a type (`com.main.service.SomeService.class;` in this case) references the class literal, which is [an object of type `Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). You can use this on **any** Java type, be it a concrete class, abstract class or an interface.

As per the Javadoc from the link above:

> Instances of the class Class represent classes **and interfaces** in a running Java application

This may be confusing if you're new, and are used to having the distinction between class and interface drummed into you, but simply speaking it's how the underlying system works (all classes and interfaces are compiled to bytecode `class` files.)

You commonly see the syntax used in dependency injection (or other uses where you need to pass the "type" of something around), as it's the easiest way of doing so.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a read and post my questions if any. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed by a **'.'** and the token class.

```
ClassLiteral:
TypeName {[ ]} . class
NumericType {[ ]} . class
boolean {[ ]} . class
void . class
```

> The type of C.class, where C is the name of a **class, interface, or
>   array type**, is Class.

A class literal evaluates to the Class object for the named type (or for void) as defined by the defining class loader  of the class of the current instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the Java docs of the method that you are using:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-

Importantly the javadoc states:

> Return the bean instance that uniquely matches the given object type,
>   if any.
>
> NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException - if more than one bean of the given
>   type was found

So if you have more that one beans extending the interface you will get exception.

Comment: No offence. I am not asking anything about spring. I am asking about interface.